# Unsure how to change the colour of application express calendar events

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have searched on-line and been through the Oracle Application Express Documentation, I cannot find how, in version 18.1, you can change the colour of the calendar events. I found something on-line which lead me to create the below SQL and use it to create the calendar entries:

```
select
      v1.meeting_id,
      v1.short_meeting_name,
      v1.start_date
      --v1.incident_or_change
      from
      (
        select 
          mtg.MEETING_ID,
          mtg.meeting_name as short_meeting_name,
          mtg.start_time as START_DATE,
          case incident_or_change 
          when 'INCIDENT' then 'apex-cal-black'
          when 'CHANGE' then 'apex-cal-blue'
          end as css_class
        from
          EBA_MTGMIN_MEETING mtg
/*
        where
          mtg.start_time > decode(nvl(:P1_SHOW_PAST_MEETINGS,'N'), 'N', localtimestamp, 'Y', localtimestamp - 3650)
        and
          lower(mtg.meeting_name) like ''|| case when instr(lower(mtg.meeting_name),lower(:P1_SEARCH)) = 0 then lower(:P1_SEARCH) else '%' end ||''
*/
        order by
          mtg.START_TIME asc, mtg.MEETING_NAME
      ) v1
```

However, I do not know how the SQL will pick up "apex-cal-black" etc to change the colour accordingly. I know it is something to do with "CSS."

Does anyone know what I need to put "where" when it comes to the "CSS" part, the code works but just doesn't do anything with the colour. What am I missing with regard to the "CSS" entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know it is something to do with "CSS."

Obviously :)

Go to calendar's **Attributes**. You'll see the **CSS Class** property (it is right above the "Export" checkboxes, which are easy to spot). From its list of values, choose `css_class` (which is name of the column returned by your query).

That's all.

Comment: Ripper bro. :-)